# Moving a PDF file from a subfolder and renaming it

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am new to the stackoverflow forums so please forgive me. Here is what I am trying to do. I have a .pdf file within two subfolders, ex: \edm\4123\gfh in the gfh directory there is a .pdf file. I need to be able to grab this PDF file, rename it, and copy it to the root directory (\edm) I am using Visual Studio 2013 and here is where I am starting from (with some code I found online)

Option Explicit On

```
Sub ListFiles()
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String


    strTopFolderName = "\\10.30.5.249\edmbursting\Olympus"

    SetAttr objFSO - CreateObject (Scripting.FileSystemObject)"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Also, I am entering this code on a module, is that correct?

Here is the code I am using now:

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
        "\\10.30.5.249\edmfiles\Olympus",
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pdf*")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile()


    Next

End Sub
```

End Module

I am having an issue when I am trying to move the file (variable: foundFile) to a location. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can use File.Copy()

```
System.IO.File.Copy("\edm\4123\gfh\FILE.pdf", "\edm\FILERENAMED.pdf")
```